# Saving a downloaded file into resources VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to download a file using webclient and save it into my application resources? something Like,

```
  Dim w As WebClient = New WebClient  
w.DownloadFile("url", *to my resources* )
```

Comment: That is not possible.  Resources are read-only after you built your program, hard-baked into the final executable file.

Answer (score 0):

Understood. it is not possible (if any one looking for this)